# CSS translate going in front vs. behind another div

Tags: html, css, svg, transform

I'm trying to translate an svg graphic in the y-axis with CSS transforms. I'm having no problem with the translate part:

```
transform: translate3d(0, -100px, 0);
```

BUT, the 100px up in the Y direction moves the svg graphic behind the parent div. I've tried putting different z-index on the various elements but can't get the svg graphic to be in front.

Here's images to show you want I mean:

[image]

And after the `translate`:

```
transform: translate3d(0, -100px, 0);
```

[image]

Comment: are you able to link us to the site where this occurs tim?

Comment: @DavidAnderton yes https://leangap.com/news. Look for the `.rocket_inner` class and you'll see when you change the `translateY` value what I mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doens't look like a z-index problem to me, but overflow. Try setting `overflow: visible` on `.svg-container` where it is currently set to hidden.

Comment: That looked to be the right answer as the svg element itself has this applied by Chrome by default: `svg:not(:root) {overflow: hidden; }`. However, when I changed that to `  overflow: visible;` the visibility was unaffected.

Answer (score 2):

Set overflow: visible on .svg-container where it is currently set to hidden. That worked for me (inspired by Hugo Silva he deserves the correct answer). I've edited his post with the amendments

**edit**

Actually this is just a partial fix, this works:

`transform: translateY(-100px) translateX(-3px);`

[image]

but this doesn't:
`transform: translateY(-100px) translateX(-3px);`

[image]

Comment: hey David, thanks. I changed .svg-container, but it still didn't have an effect.

Comment: I figured it out there was an `overflow:hidden` set on `.media, .media-body ` higher up the DOM. So frustrating, but thanks for your help!

Comment: Also I noted `svg:not(:root) {  overflow: hidden; }` is being set by chrome. glad you got it sorted!